# Running backwards on a carousel

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, rotational-kinematics, coriolis-effect

Let's suppose I'm on a carousel rotating with a speed $\omega$ and start running on it in the opposite direction with a speed $v$ such that $\omega r=-v$ where $r$ is the distance between me and the center of the carousel.
What are the forces that act on me? Do I feel Coriolis force?

Intuitively I'm "still" so no force should act on me, but also intuitively this explanation seems too easy to be the real one.

Comment: My brain hurts, as $\theta$ is usually a measure of angle, and not of rotational speed. $\dot \theta$ would improve the situation here, or $\omega$ also.

Comment: FWIW: Regardless of what you feel, "Coriolis force" is a [_ficticious force_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fictitious_force) that we use to explain motion in a rotating coordinate system. The forces that act on you are what they are, and you will feel what you feel, but how you describe those things and what you _call_ them depends on whether you choose to write your description with respect to the rotating frame of the carousel or, with respect to an inertial frame (e.g., as seen by an observer who is standing on the ground beside the carousel.)

Comment: @SolomonSlow:  What's more, the equivalence principle says that you don't "feel" any fictitious forces that act on you (and also that gravity is a fictitious force.)

Comment: I think that about Coriolis force what I meant was "does the Coriolis force appear in the motion equation of my movent with regard to the rotating object"?

Comment: How is this different from running on a treadmill?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As viewed in an inertial frame, no force acts on you.  This makes sense, because you are at rest in that frame.

As viewed in the rotating reference frame attached to the carousel, two forces are acting on you:  the Coriolis force and the centrifugal force.  The Coriolis force has magnitude $2 m \omega v = 2 m \omega^2 r$ inwards.  The centrifugal force has magnitude $m \omega^2 r$ outwards.  Thus, in the rotating reference frame there is a net force of $m \omega^2 r$ inwards.  This is completely in line with your motion in the rotating reference frame, since in that frame you are executing uniform circular motion about the origin with radius $r$ and angular frequency $\omega$.

Comment: The last part is actually very smart and exactly the answer I was looking for (the mathematical side is something I could have computed myself but had no willpower to do)

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean that you remain stationary while the carousel spins underneath you. This means that the net force acting on you must be zero, or that you would only feel the reaction to your weight from your feet.

If you closed your eyes it would feel like you are running on a straight line, except because your feet are a certain distance apart, and the carousel has different speeds under each foot, it would feel like running on two treadmills, (one per foot) each with a different speed.