# Coriolis force on a person on a carousel

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames, centripetal-force, centrifugal-force, coriolis-effect

Good afternoon all,

I am looking at the question [Running backwards on a carousel](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/600641/running-backwards-on-a-carousel) from 2020 and the accepted answer given below it. Why is there no centripetal force on the person in either reference frame? In the inertial frame, I would guess that it is because the person is at rest with respect to this frame and is therefore not undergoing circular motion, but is this correct? What would be the explanation regarding the rotating reference frame?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is centripedal force in the rotating reference frame. Your explanation for the nonrotating reference frame was right. The accepted answer of that question says there is a net inward force of $m\omega^2r$ in the rotating reference frame. This is the centripetal force that keeps the person on a rotating path in the rotating reference frame.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer, @AndrewChristensen. If I could clarify, does that mean that the centripetal force in the rotating frame is the net force produced by the two fictitious forces (Coriolis force and centrifugal force)?

Comment: Yes that's right.

Comment: Thanks very much, @AndrewChristensen, your answers have been most helpful.